# SQL DateTime alternative to only HH:MM:SS for easy coding in C# Linq

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, linq

Hi guys I am looking for the proper Datatype. Basically I only need time in HH:MM:SS for an SQL Record. I am confused to choose between `string,` `Int(seconds)` or some SQL variation of `DATETIME` that makes it easy for in terms of Coding to sort, select, display etc using Linq-C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `Time` datatype or convert your datetime to `'hh:mm:ss'` - `convert(nvarchar(8), <your column>, 108)`

Comment: what would be the equivalent datatype in c# for a MVC Dbcontext Model?